# How does pnpm's node_modules structure avoid circular symlinks?

Tags: linking, package-managers

I'm reading this article explaining the node_modules structure of `pnpm`.
https://pnpm.js.org/en/symlinked-node-modules-structure
It states next to the bolded text `avoid circular symlinks` that `dependencies of packages are placed in the same folder in which the dependent packages are`.

I get the next sentence it doesn't matter which `node_modules` folder dependencies are in since node will continue to look one level up for a `node_modules` folder, but I don't get how circular symlinks are avoided.

So how does this avoid circular symlinks?